# LXC: systemd fails after the 19th container

Tags: systemd, lxc

I am running LXC on Archlinux.

I have a combination of Arch, Fedora, Centos, Debian, and Ubuntu LXC containers, each based on systemd.

If I try to open more than 19 LXC containers, the 20th container will start, but without systemd running inside.  (`ps aux` shows just `bash`, `init`, and `ps`)

I thought this might be related to the number of open files, since a centos container will sometimes report "too many open files" when I run `poweroff` inside of it while I have a large number of LXC containers running.  But I increased the file limits [as described in this link](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/), rebooted and verified the changes, but my problem persists.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You need to explain in the question how you know that that `init` is not systemd, and what program it instead is.

Comment: @JdeBP I guess I didn't know that `init` could be systemd.  But when I run `ps aux` on the same container while everything works, I see a large number of other processes like `systemd-journald`, `systemd-networkd`, and importantly for my purposes, `/usr/bin/sshd -D` which is started by systemd.  When things are not working, nothing related to systemd works, such as `systemctl status sshd` or `poweroff`.  I just get this error: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Which Linux variant is your 20th container running, and how much system memory is available before after it starts?

Comment: @MarkStosberg I confirmed the same behavior where the 20th container was Fedora, Arch, or Ubuntu, and sometimes (but not always) Debian.  As far as memory goes, I am pretty sure I was running at around 15GB of memory available (out of 32GB, but no swap enabled).  I can't check because today the problem seems to not want to reproduce.  This has been bugging me for a couple weeks and when I got it to reproduce through multiple reboots I posted the question... but the issue seems to be not reproducing at the moment \*deep, dejected sigh\*

Comment: OK, so the issue probably isn't with 20th container but something else that sometimes correlates with it. This is a pretty specific issue-- I would try an LXC-specific support channel like a mailing list, IRC channel, etc if available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Error: Too many open files" while starting service in environment with several LXCs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747085/error-too-many-open-files-while-starting-service-in-environment-with-several)

Comment: I tried to mark it as duplicate twice. As it failed twice, I undeleted my ... duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem happens with non-privileged (ie: using user namespaces) containers, rather than privileged (ie: root) containers, I believe this would be caused by a restricted limit on the use of the inotify interface for the same user running containers. Apparently systemd relies on inotify. The Debian buster LXC package includes a setting loosening the sysctl `fs.inotify.max_user_instances` in [`/etc/sysctl.d/30-lxc-inotify.conf`](https://salsa.debian.org/lxc-team/lxc/blob/debian/1%253.1.0+really3.0.3-7/debian/lxc.sysctl):

> ```
> # Defines the maximum number of inotify listeners.
> # By default, this value is 128, which is quickly exhausted when using
> # systemd-based LXC containers (15 containers are enough).
> # When the limit is reached, systemd becomes mostly unusable, throwing
> # "Too many open files" all around (both on the host and in containers).
> # See https://kdecherf.com/blog/2015/09/12/systemd-and-the-fd-exhaustion/
> # Increase the user inotify instance limit to allow for about
> # 100 containers to run before the limit is hit again
> fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 1024
> ```

The [relevant documentation for this setting](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/inotify.7#/proc_interfaces) tells:

> `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances`
>       This specifies an upper limit on the number of inotify instances that can be created per real user ID.

If your LXC installation doesn't include such a setting, you could check if simply running on the host:

```
sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
```

will fix the problem.

Comment: Neat!  I am not currently in a position to reproduce the bug and check if this works, but I will come back and mark the answer as correct if it does.

Comment: I just found after answering https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747085/error-too-many-open-files-while-starting-service-in-environment-with-several that I already made an answer here. Anyway here OP never validated this answer and appears MIA while my new answer has been (and has more information about root/non-root). So deleting this answer before voting to have the (old) question set as duplicate of the new question.