# "Error: Too many open files" while starting service in environment with several LXCs

Tags: linux, lxc

**Environment:**

I am using a CentOS-7 as a hypervisor for running several LXCs under `libvirt`. Each container runs a minimal installation of CentOS-7 with cut down FreePBX (Asterisk, Apache, MySQL + bits).

**Symptoms:**

There are 16 containers running without any problems. When I start one more it does start, but after the 17th container starts I can not do `systemctl start/restart/stop <anything>` in ANY of the containers:

```
[root@test-lxc ~]# systemctl restart dnsmasq
Error: Too many open files
```

**Diagnostics:**

The following diagnostics and counts are done while the 17th LXC is running and `systemctl restart blabla` is failing:

I can ssh into any LXC and run most basic commands, e.g. ls, etc. I suspect the limit somehow affects only the `systemd`.

I'm trying to understand where/why I hit the limit.

```
[root@lxc-hypervisor]# sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 29616      0       12988463
```

That was not tweaked, this is just what happened to be from the default install. Same as above maximum (last) value = 12988463 is reported by the hypervisor and also inside each LXC. Very similar 1st value just under 30000 is also reported in each LXC.

When I try to count file descriptors across all process inside each LXC I get in the order 400 ~ 500 in each LXC.

```
for pid in $( ls /proc/ | grep -E -e "^[0-9][0-9]*\$" ); do
    ls -l /proc/${pid}/fd/ 2> /dev/null | wc -l
done
```

The sum total around 9000 (9k) without the hypervisor itself. When I run that on the hypervisor I usually get suspiciously close values just over 10000 e.g. 10005.

**Questions:**

Q1. Where is the limit set or inherited from?

Q2. Why does the limit affect `systemctl start/stop/restart blah` commands, but I can still ssh into LXCs, run commands such as bash scripts with loops that fork a lot, albeit as root.

Q3. How to tweak limits to allow running more LXCs. To the best of my understanding RAM and other resources are not the limit.

I did read many articles and answers on the subject of file descriptor limits, but I fail to see where my system hits the limits.

Any other relevant information is also welcome.

Comment: Can you share with us the `ulimit -Hn` output?

Comment: @K-att- on the host/hypervisor from a ssh root shell the `ulimit -Hh` outputs `4096` and on the LXC it outputs `8192`. A.B's answer solved my problem, but I am happy to explore other queries and answer more comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are not hitting a global limit, but an *inotify* limit. This would be seen on containers running *systemd* because *systemd* uses the *inotify* facility for its bookkeeping, but the host would also be affected. Containers not using *systemd* (nor *inotify*) would probably be unaffected.

> [`/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/inotify.7#/proc_interfaces):
>
> This specifies an upper limit on the number of inotify instances that
> can be created per real user ID.

If only non-rootless (ie: *root* in the container is the real *root*) containers are in use, then *root* user becomes the bottleneck. Having multiple containers using the same rootless user mapping would also create such bottleneck for this container's *root* user (but not affect the host). The default is 128, far too little for containers use.

CentOS7 (or Rocky9) doesn't include any default setup for this with LXC. [Debian-based distributions include](https://salsa.debian.org/lxc-team/lxc/-/commit/0002e9287e362de52b2ef4b47e028e400397d65f) this file on the host:

[`/etc/sysctl.d/30-lxc-inotify.conf`](https://salsa.debian.org/lxc-team/lxc/-/blob/debian/1%255.0.2-1/debian/lxc.sysctl?ref_type=tags):

```
# Defines the maximum number of inotify listeners.
# By default, this value is 128, which is quickly exhausted when using
# systemd-based LXC containers (15 containers are enough).
# When the limit is reached, systemd becomes mostly unusable, throwing
# "Too many open files" all around (both on the host and in containers).
# See https://kdecherf.com/blog/2015/09/12/systemd-and-the-fd-exhaustion/
# Increase the user inotify instance limit to allow for about
# 100 containers to run before the limit is hit again
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 1024
```

So you should do the same by creating this file on the host. For immediate effect (on the host):

```
sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
```